# How to store this json data in an array

Tags: angular

[View json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr7GX.png)

```
export class XComponent implements OnInit {
      plans: any;
      totalSubscriber = []
    constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
        activatedRoute.data.subscribe((res)=>{
          this.plans = res.plansresolve.data;
        });
```

All that json data is in `plans` property.
Currently I am hard coding `totalSubscriber = [2500,5000, and so on....]`

How do I take all the total subscribers from the json data and store it in the array as you see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` :

```
this.totalSubscriber  = this.plans.map((plan) => plan.subscriber_count);
```